# How to change a field in parent class while creating chiled class fields in forms.py and views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm was creating ModelForm I try to make change the parent class while saving child class fields to the database, in the views.py I made but it didn't save to the database.
here is my model.py

```
class Table(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    taple = models.OneToOneField(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_people_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.people.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        People.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Class People is the child class and Table is the parent class so I'm using People class for making forms. here is my forms.py

```
class Booking(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = People
        fields = [
            'taple',
        ]
```

So I want to make **True** *book field in Table class* and save it to the database when saving Booking form. here is my views.py

```
def booking(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            people_instance = People.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except Table.DoesNotExist:
            people_instance = People(user=request.user)
        form = Booking(request.POST, instance=people_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.taple.booking = True
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.user = request.user
            user.taple = form.cleaned_data.get('taple')
            user.save()
            print(user.taple.booking, user.taple.id)
            return redirect('booked')
    else:
        form = Booking()
    return render(request, 'main/booking.html', {'form': form})
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from the snippets is that you want to be able to record if a table is booked (book Boolean Field in your Table model and if so by whom, which is the object of your People model.

If my understanding is correct, then I don't think you really need a join table (People model). Instead, I would change your model as follow:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booked_by = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='table_booked')

    @property
    def is_booked(self):
        # This returns True if booked_by is set, False otherwise
        return self.booked_by_id is not None
```

This way you don't need the People model. The property decorator will allow you to use is_booked as a calculated field. 
Also, note the related name which will be used in the form:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    table_booked = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Table.objects.filter(booked_by__isnull=True))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['table_booked',]
```

In the form, you will see that we define a custom queryset for table_booked. THe aim is to filter for free tables only.

Then you can hopefully simplify as well your view as follow:

Update:
As table_booked is a reverse foreign key, we actually need to save the table object which contains the relation. Here is the modified view:

```
@login_required
def booking(request):
    form = BookingForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        tbl = form.cleaned_data['table_booked']
        tbl.booked_by = request.user
        tbl.save()
        user.save()
        print(request.user.table_booked.id, request.user.table_booked.is_booked)
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'booking/booking.html', {'form': form})
```

Note: I haven't tested the code so there could be some typos but that should help you getting started.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: Yes you understand my question, thank you geek and I will test the code.

Comment: Bro you didn't declare that `user` variable

Comment: I get this error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'is_booked' into field. Choices are: booked_by, booked_by_id, restaurant, restaurant_id` when I try makemigrations

Comment: My bad, it's not possible to use a property for database operations such as filtering. BookingForm should be amended as follow: table_booked = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Table.objects.filter(booked_by__isnull=True))

Comment: Regarding user, meant to refer to the authenticated user (request.user).

Comment: I get this error again `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /booking/` this is from views

Comment: `print(request.user.table_booked.id, request.user.table_booked.is_booked)`

Comment: I've updated the answer, this should now fix the issue. we were missing to save the table object, which contains the foreign key. I've just tried the changes in a django instance, and this is working on my side.

Comment: bro  `table_booked = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Table.objects.filter(booked_by__isnull=True))`  this queryset shows the available tables. So how to show specific restaurants tables?

Comment: That's a different question. So you should open a new one. Also look at the django documentation for models and relationships.